# Receiving an Xcode error when running app on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

"error: failed to attach to process ID 0" I try deleting all deprived data, cleaning project, changing name of resources folder and still cant run this specific app. I can however run other apps. What else could be causing this error?

Comment: quit your simulator and then run again or reset Content and settings of simulator.

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1. delete the build of your project from organizer
2. clean the project by pressing cmd+shift+k
3. delete the app from your simulator
4. most important, make sure you run the project by using developer provisioning